# Remove conflicting styling - Bootstrap & Google Custom Search

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-search

Take a look at the picture below from my website: www.kokorugs.com

I am using Boostrap and I believe that there are some conflicting CSS styles.

The problem is that I cannot see Google's CSS and can't figure out how to override this styling.

[image]

My code (from google) is below:

```
        <aside class="box" style="padding:10px 0;">

            <script>
              (function() {
                var cx = '009058734720051694368:e41h4lf-hsk';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
              })();
            </script>
            <gcse:search></gcse:search> 


        </aside>
```

My CSS for the "box" class is irrelevant but I will include it to avoid any questions:

```
.box {
background: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #bcd78d;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
margin-top: 10px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I appreciate any help in removing this double border. Thank you!

UPDATE:

When I tried this CSS rule:

```
* {
    border: none !important;
}
```

only Google's border was removed.  The picture is below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border is applied from this section of bootstrap-combined.min.css :

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
-webkit-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
-moz-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
-o-transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
}
```

So removing the border shadows will fix this for you:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
```

Or overriding it can help too:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: Good progress.  Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKrTF/  -----The shadow is gone now, but the focus remains and it overlaps google's box. Any ideas?

Comment: Great! Just need to add `margin-top:-1px;` to the input box for that. For example `#gs_tti0 > input {margin-top:-1px !important;}`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SKrTF/3/

Comment: The good news is that on my site, the problem is fixed. The only thing I can't understand is that on the jsFiddle, bootstrap's styling is overlapping Google's. The margin-top: -1px didn't work either. But I guess it could be something weird with jsFiddle. If you have any ideas, please let me know!  For now, I'll mark the answer though since technically my original question is answered =)

Comment: Thanks! `{margin-top:-1px !important;}` fixes the overlap for me, even on jsfiddle. Did you check this jsfiddle.net/SKrTF/3 ?

Answer (score 1):

The second border you are seeing is in fact not a border but a box shadow. It is beeing added by your bootstrap css to all inputs, but not desired for the search box. You should turn it off by countering it for the search box only. Add something like this to your css:

```
.gsc-input-box input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Good progress. Take a look at this jsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/SKrTF -----The shadow is gone now, but the focus remains and it overlaps google's box. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by overlap?

Comment: Do you not see it in the jsFiddle?  jsfiddle.net/SKrTF/1 ---it seems like the bootstraps styling is overlapping google's input box. Google's green box border is being hidden on the bottom side by bootstrap's now all white input.

Answer (score 1):

for complete correction of the conflict use

```
input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button:hover, input.gsc-search-button:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-shadow: none;
}


input.gsc-input, .gsc-input-box, .gsc-input-box-hover, .gsc-input-box-focus {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I did not realize box-sizing was my enemy there.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following CSS and it works for me:

```
.gsc-input-box input[type="text"], .gsc-input-box input[type="text"]:focus, .gsc-input-box input[type="text"]:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

---

line-height: normal;

does the work of removing the text popping out of text box.

I have also documented the fix for Google custom search showing scroll bars in search results tab here:
http://www.am22tech.com/google-custom-search-input-box-conflicting-bootstrap-css/