# Google CSE with Twitter Bootstrap not displaying the search box correctly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-custom-search

The Google Custom Search (CSE) not displaying the search box and the button correctly. 
I am using Twitter Bootstrap v3.1.0.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = '009077552906670546181:2ufng0dmsos';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
            '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Can anyone please help?

http://jsfiddle.net/nz6rh/

[screenshot of the abnormal searchbox](https://plus.google.com/112120100514518739003/posts/7S8Y8euw1Ti)

Comment: Please share jsfiddle link?

Comment: Tried your code in jsfiddle. Working fine I guess. http://jsfiddle.net/Bq4Pz/

Comment: What exactly the issue with button and search box?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954381/remove-conflicting-styling-boostrap-google-custom-search

Comment: It seems the problem is not duplicate or I could not solve my problem with the provided solution. Updated the JSFiddle to simulate the problem.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  The way I solved it was by using Firebug in firefox.  I inspected the google custom search engine input field and disabled css rules from my custom css files that looked suspicious one by one until I hit on one that fixed it.  In my particular case there was a margin on all `table` elements.  Removing that fixed the issue.  Firebug (or a similar tool) will save you I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same problem. It is not the best solution, but until this solution comes... it could help you. Try adding this to your CSS file with your own colours and measures:

```
.gsc-search-button
{
    background-color: #1a4195;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button:hover, input.gsc-search-button:focus {
    background-color: #1a4195 !important;
    background-image: url("http://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/search_box_icon.png") !important;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 16px !important;
    border-color: #1a4195 !important;
    filter: none;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

I have used the following CSS to resolve the Bootstrap conflict:

```
input.gsc-input,
.gsc-input-box,
.gsc-input-box-hover,
.gsc-input-box-focus,
.gsc-search-button {
    box-sizing: content-box; 
    line-height: normal;
}
```

You can check the working example here (I use Bootstrap 3.2 currently):
http://www.am22tech.com/google-custom-search-input-box-conflicting-bootstrap-css/

Comment: The accepted answer did not fix styling on the input box with google CSE and Bootstrap 3.  This answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Per getbootstrap.com:

> Some third party software, including Google Maps and Google Custom Search Engine, conflict >with Bootstrap due to * { box-sizing: border-box; }

Check the [Third party support section](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties) for some work-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

From https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/bUtHfTZ_HYM, I got:

```
.gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family : inherit;
}

.gsc-control-cse .gsc-input-box {
    height : inherit;
}

input.gsc-input,
.gsc-input-box,
.gsc-input-box-hover,
.gsc-input-box-focus,
.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    box-sizing  : content-box;
    line-height : normal;
    margin-top  : 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this:

-Add this code on the .css of your site:

```
.gsc-results-wrapper-overlay, .gsc-results-wrapper-visible, .gsc-search-button, .gsc-search-button-v2 {
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

CSS:

```
#gsc-i-id1 {
    position: relative;
    left: -7px;
    top: -4px;
}

input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    height: 26px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    min-width: 13px !important;
    padding: 5px 26px !important;
    width: 68px !important;
}
```

Comment: First CSS Block fixes the offset of type-box; second one fixes the search button. Source for Second CSS Block: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799768/8067338