# Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) button image missing / not appearing

Tags: css, google-custom-search

After implementing a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) and adding their JavaScript code to the Master Page for my site, I saw the search box and button but the button had no text or image on it.  It was just a blank gray bar, as shown below.
[image: CSE with no button image]

The gray button is supposed to have an image of a magnifying glass.  This is the JavaScript code provided by Google, so it seemed to me that was all that was available to change:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var cx = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

I tried adding an inline style to gcse element to increase the height, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was a CSS issue and a CSS fix was [provided by Wes on appfinite](http://appfinite.com/topic/google-custom-search-box-and-button-is-squished/).  Google has created a CSS class for the button and the style attributes of the class can be overridden.  So I just added the following CSS style section to the `<head>` section of my Master Page and that solved the problem:

```
<style>
    .cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2,
    input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
        height: 26px !important;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        min-width: 13px !important;
        padding: 5px 26px !important;
        width: 68px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You don't need .cse and .gsc-search-button. Also  input.gsc-search-button-v2 is added twice.

Comment: It seems that (nowadays?) `.gsc-search-button` is a `button`, not `input`, so these CSS rules do not match the button anymore.

Answer (score 1):

2 things are important to get this to work. Rest can be styled as per your needs.

```
.cse .gsc-search-button-v2, .gsc-search-button-v2 {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    min-width: 13px !important;
}

.gsc-search-button-v2 svg {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `box-sizing` problem. Just add `box-sizing: content-box;` will solve it.

```
.gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2,
input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```