# Bootstrap design on google search box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i personalize the basic Google Search Box with a simple bootstrap design? I want my search box look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOGWr.png).

Here is the html where I want to include the search

> ```
>           <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
>                   <div class="input-group">
>                       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cautare" name="q">
>                       <div class="input-group-btn">
>                           <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
>                       </div>
>                   </div>
>               </form>
> ```

Here is the basic google css and java script.

And look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozvx.png).

I try many things. Maybe for you it's simple so please do not criticize me because I did not know anything about javascript.

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left nav-search">
                    <div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
                <script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>

                <script type='text/javascript'>
                google.load('search', '1', {language: 'ro', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
                  var customSearchOptions = {};
                  var orderByOptions = {};
                  orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
                  customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
                  customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
                  customSearchOptions['overlayResults'] = true;
                  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('014984999857089792589:fqyliftt9go', customSearchOptions);
                  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
                  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
                  options.setAutoComplete(true);
                  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
                }, true);
                </script>
<style type='text/css'>
  .gsc-control-cse {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  input.gsc-input, .gsc-input-box, .gsc-input-box-hover, .gsc-input-box-focus {
    border-color: #D9D9D9;
  }
  input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button:hover, input.gsc-search-button:focus {
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    background-image: none;
    filter: none;

  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhInactive {
    border-color: #FF9900;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhActive {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border-bottom-color: #FF9900
  }
  .gsc-tabsArea {
    border-color: #FF9900;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-imageResult:hover {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link b  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active b {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-page {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  a.gsc-trailing-more-results:link {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-webResult .gs-snippet, .gs-imageResult .gs-snippet, .gs-fileFormatType {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl, .gs-imageResult div.gs-visibleUrl {
    color: #008000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    color: #008000;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short  {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-long {
    display: block;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
    display: none;
  }
  .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-long  {
    display: block;
  }
  .gsc-cursor-box {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-page {
    border-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-current-page {
    border-color: #FF9900;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion {
    border-color: #336699;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .gsc-completion-title {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gsc-completion-snippet {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:link,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:link *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:link  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:visited {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:hover  {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion a.gs-title:active,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:active *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:active {
    color: #0000CC;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-snippet, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right * {
    color: #000000;
  }
  .gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl,.gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl-short  {
    color: #008000;
  }
</style>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the below link. Let me know if its working fine with you.

http://jsfiddle.net/XfzFQ/614/

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Yea, but how can I connect that on google search box? O.O I Have the css and html from Bootstrap but .. I need to use css bootstrap on google search box

Comment: Please refer the link..          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954381/remove-conflicting-styling-bootstrap-google-custom-searc...